# How to keep checkout button at the bottom on mobile web?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing a complicated mobile web app using [Snap.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/)

There is a checkout button that I want to keep at the bottom of the page at all times, before & during scroll. I am unable to do so, I keep getting this:

[image]

The viewport set is
`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

In a nutshell, this is the HTML/CSS:

```
<html>
<body>
...
<div id="content">
<div id="page">
<div id="toolbar">
<div id="bottomArea">$0.00 Current Order 0</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And relevant CSS

```
#toolbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 44px;
}
#page {
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
html, body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#bottomArea {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I've tried a series of CSS solutions, and I'm not sure what to do - right now, the only thing that kind of works is a jQuery solution, however, this is very jittery and looks very bad as the user scrolls.

```
        $("#bottomArea").show();
        x = String(52-$("#content").scrollTop())+"px";
        $("#bottomArea").css("bottom",x);
        $("#content").scroll(function() {
          x = String(52-$("#content").scrollTop())+"px"
          $("#bottomArea").css("bottom",x)
        });
```

Any idea how I might be able to fix this issue in a better way?

Comment: `bottom: 0;` should do the trick. Can you share a full example? Maybe there's another issue on the rest of the HTML. A working snippet would be great.

Comment: @Veehmot it is insanely long, but here you go: https://paste.ee/p/RHIpQ#8cQEHqRZXZEiOkG7P4KLTfwQ8B1W09EN - I put relevant external stylesheets inline